# How to capture website hits using Android App Plugin

Tags: java, javascript, android

I am new to android app development is there any plugin that capture different webpages to get user interactions with webpage UI,user device name,user session,user time spend on a particular screen and display those records on my mobile application.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be google analytics. Its pretty straightforward and well documented.

See here : [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please quote the most relevant part of the link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think if we use Google Analytics we can track users who run into our own application but my point is i want to capture the different others websites records using some code to create a plugin which will automatically get the records based on the different websites ID and display those records on my app.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you have a web application for mobile,
What about [clicktale](http://www.clicktale.com/) ?
it shows a full report of clicks like hitmap and more, also google analytics is one of the best free users analysing tool, you can combine many tools using the [google tag manager](http://www.google.com/tagmanager/), its actually a industry by itself 
I would recommend using [clickale](http://www.clicktale.com/) and [google analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics) at first.